# sentiment analysis of sentences in python using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

i have this python code in which what i intend to do is provide some input to the three different polarity analyzers. But the problem is which one is more reliable and widely used.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.sentiment.util import *
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as sia



text=["i have a good feeling about this."]
text1='she has the worse character in the class'

sid=sia()
for word in text:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(word)
    print ss



nltk.sentiment.util.demo_vader_instance(text1)
nltk.sentiment.util.demo_liu_hu_lexicon(text1, plot=False)
```

the output is as follows:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.405, 'pos': 0.595, 'compound': 0.5267}
{'neg': 0.307, 'neu': 0.693, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.4767}
Negative
>>>
```

if there is any other way to analyze sentences and find out if the user is happy,sad or neutral...then please feel free to give ideas.

Also how do i decide from the polarity values if the user is happy,sad or neutral?